# How to disable session caching of a web site served through IIS?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, iis, web-config, redmine

I have a website that is served through IIS. If I log into the system, an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS appears. Such an error will only appear in Chrome, but not in IE. I am sure the error is in the cache. How to prevent chrome session caching?

I tried disabling client-side caching, as shown in web.config, but this does not help.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="0" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Are you trying to serve Redmine this way?

Comment: yes, I try to serve Redmine

Comment: You must use reverse proxy to serve it. Which version of IIS? Seek for reverse proxy how to do, for your version. I was doing it but on IIS 8 I think with URL rewrite module...

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded Redmine (3.4.11 (2019-06-10) -> 4.0.4 (2019-06-10))